# SS Reporting Services - Merge 2 and 3 Rows grouping by first column

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I've the following matrix:

```
FIELD_A   TYPE  THRESHOLD   VALUE
D01        A        1         7
E01        A        1         8
E03        A        1         9
H04        B        3         9
```

And I'm trying with a Matrix have the following structure:

[image]

How can I do this using Reporting Services?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in reporting services.  When using row groups, you can only rowspan in the group headers.  Subgroup/detail columns cannot be to the left of the group header.  The closest you can get would be 
TYPE - THRESHOLD - FIELD_A - VALUE